# Detect if point within current view area?

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry

i want to check if the current view area contains Point(x,y).

My input for this case is :

1) Point (lat, lng)

2) Current view (minLatitude, minLongitude, maxLatitude, maxLongitude)

Any java lib can do it?

Thank!

Comment: Oh come on, this is just 4 comparisons!

Comment: In total one if statement with 4 conditions. why would you need a lib for that?

Comment: this is my java function with google map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Rectangle2D.Double ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Rectangle2D.Double.html)) and method `contains(x, y)`.

```
Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(minLatitude, minLongitude, maxLatitude - minLatitude, maxLongitude - minLongitude);
boolean isInView = rect.contains(lat, lng);
```

Comment: Can i convert (minLatitude, minLongitude, maxLatitude, maxLongitude) to Rectangle2D object?

Comment: You can create new Rectangle2D object using constructor accepting (x,y,width,height). Then you can ask if some point lies within the rectangle region using contains(x,y)